# Changing margin programmatically using sdp

Tags: android, margin

I am using `compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'` api for setting margins of linear layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Now when I change the margin programatically, it changes it in dp not in sdp

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.setMargins(0, 10, 10, 0);
layout_message.setLayoutParams(params);
```

So how to change the margin programatically according to sdp? Thank you

Comment: why are you using this sdp?

Comment: It adjusts your app layout design for different screen sizes implicitly, means if you are building your app for a mobile device using sdp then the same design dimensions would appear on the tablet device screen, you don't need to perform it explicitly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try

**For Java**

```
int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._10sdp);
params.setMargins(0, margin, margin, 0);
```

**For Kotlin** as pointed out by [Zohab Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5361964/zohab-ali)

```
resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._10sdp)
```

Comment: for kotlin `resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._10sdp)`